# If condition not checking the condition

Tags: php, if-statement

```
function pokemon2()
{
    include 'details.php';

    $damage = $_POST['attack']; 
    $oppo_health = $_SESSION['oppo_health']; 
    if($oppo_health < 0)
    {
        echo "Died!"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $oppo_path = $_SESSION['path'];
        echo "<br />";
        echo $oppo_path;
        echo "<br />"; 
        $oppo_health = $oppo_health - $damage;
        echo $oppo_health;
        $_SESSION['attack'] = $damage; 
        $_SESSION['oppo_health'] = $oppo_health;
    }
}
```

The code should display 'Died' if the `$oppo_health` goes below 0! 
But its not happening as it should?? The logic is correct and no errors shown.

Comment: Have you debug by echoing value of `$oppo_health` ?

Comment: Also just as a side note, `<=` would be better, as if they equal `0` hp, they die also (not just below 0).

Comment: Are you sure the session is kept between calls to "pokemon2" ?

Comment: use var_dump($_SESSION['oppo_health']) and var_dump($oppo_health) to see them.

Comment: Rikesh Yup I have tried checking the values, they are prefect.

BeatAlex I have also tried it, but still I will try it once more and tell you.

BartłomiejWach pokemon1() is having different session values as well as names, so actually it should not be getting affected for that reason :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a session by using session_start() method.